# Wrap final Typsecript export in module?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, typescript

I have a bunch of models and services which I need to export within a TS module.

## Source

**models/User.ts**

```
import {IModel} from "./IModel";

export interface User extends IModel {
    // ...
}
```

**services/UserService.ts**

```
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {HttpClient} from 'aurelia-fetch-client';
import {BaseService} from "./BaseService";
import {User as ModelType} from "../models/User";

@inject(HttpClient)
export class UserService extends BaseService<ModelType> { 
    // ...
}
```

## Dist

Here's what I want in the end, after building the project. Not necessarily verbatim, but in general I want my root module `my-module` to contain a sub-module for `models` and one for `services` -- or allow me to access things in such a way that models/services are not bundled under the same "container" (e.g. to avoid name conflicts between models/services).

**dist/index.d.ts**

```
declare module "my-module/models" {
    export interface User { ... }
    // ... other models here ...
}

declare module "my-module/services" {
    export class UserService { ... }
    // ... other models here ...
}
```

So that I can install this package via `npm` and use it in another project like this:

```
import {User} from "my-module/models";
import {UserService} from "my-module/services";
```

- There are a lot of models/services, so I don't want to have to manually maintain/build an `index.ts` to wrangle them all.
- How should I structure my Typescript project?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like `typings bundle` does exactly what you need. It will combine all your declaration files and dependencies into one file.

Let's say eg. I have an module called "stackoverflow" that has two files (stackoverflow.ts and constants.ts). index.ts depends on both an external library (eg. bluebird) and constants.ts.

**stackoverflow.ts**

```
import { PromisifyOptions } from 'bluebird'
export { FIRST } from './constants'

export interface thePromiseUsingInterface {
  options: PromisifyOptions
}
```

**constants.ts**

```
export const FIRST = 1
export const SECOND = 2
```

To generate the master declaration file:

1. generate your declaration files :`tsc --delcaration`)
2. bundle the declaration files and their dependencies into index.d.ts:
   `typings bundle -o index.d.ts`

When you publish your library to npm, make sure to also include your typings.json.

In your other project, you can then `npm install stackoverflow` and start using it:

```
import * as constants from 'stackoverflow/constants'
console.log(constants.SECOND)
```

For reference here is a [gist with all the relevant files](https://gist.github.com/pellejacobs/2dba563d372a43049ce083a5772ff4c9): stackoverflow.ts, constants.ts, index.d.ts, package.json, typings.